# jaxb: How can I bind nested element

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

There is my xml:

```
<parent>
   <children>
      <child>1</child>
      <child>2</child>
   </children>
</parent>
```

I want to have the following Parent class:

```
@XmlRootElement
Parent{
   @XmlElement(name="children/child") 
   List<Child> children;
}
```

I don't want to have class for element 'children'.
How should I map field children ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `@XmlElementWrapper`:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Parent {
   @XmlElementWrapper(name="children")
   @XmlElement(name="child") 
   List<Child> children;
}
```